# Hide the .html at the end of my website url

Tags: java, html, css, .htaccess

I have tried to remove the .html at the end of my url with this code in my .htaccess file, but it continues to say that the file for the other pages is missing when I load it up.

```
# mod_rewrite starts here

RewriteEngine on

# does not apply to existing directories, meaning if the folder exists on the server then don't change anything and don't run the Rule!

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Check for file in directory with .html extension

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

# Here we actually show the page that has the .html extension

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]s
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name it index.html then make folders and make index inside of them.

So if you want website.com/home for example make a folder inside the public_html and name it home and make that file name index.